# How to do a partial download in Google Drive Api v3?

Tags: python, download, header, google-drive-api

The documentation says [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#partial_download) that you need to use the Range header `Range: bytes=500-999`.

**My code**

```
def downloadChunkFromFile(file_id, start, length):
    headers = {"Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(start, start+length)}
    #How do I insert the headers?
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request, chunksize=length)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    return fh.getvalue()
```

How do I use the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve the partial download of the file from Google Drive using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to download the file from Google Drive using Drive API with your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the range property like `Range: bytes=500-999` is required to be included in the request header. This has already been mentioned in your question.

  - For `request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)`, it includes the range property in the header.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request, chunksize=length)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
return fh.getvalue()
```

To:

```
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
request.headers["Range"] = "bytes={}-{}".format(start, start+length)
fh = io.BytesIO(request.execute())
return fh.getvalue()
```

#### Note:

- In above modified script, when `MediaIoBaseDownload` is used, it was found that the file is completely downloaded without using the range property. So I don't use `MediaIoBaseDownload`.
- Also you can use `requests` like as follows.

  ```
  url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media"
  headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer ###accessToken###", "Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(start, start+length)}
  res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  fh = io.BytesIO(res.content)
  return fh.getvalue()
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Partial download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#partial_download)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.